# How to translate ui file + several questions

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtranslator

I have a problem with translations which are only partial. I create my ui graphical interfaces with Qt Designer. Based on a chapter in a book on PyQt5, I have been able to translate an application in the past without using Qt Designer.

But I had never translated interfaces made with it. In fact, to be precise
I have a partial translation. It concerns the strings that I introduced in the code of the application (setToolTip, setStatusTip, ....) but not the rest. I can switch between carefree english and french either without doing anything (for french) or by forcing it ex:

`python start_app.py en_EN`

I'm on Manjaro, python 3.8, pyqt5.14.2.

Is my code bad? Did I miss something?

- I also have 3 other points to clarify regarding these translations:
  Is it necessary to include all the project files in order to benefit from the translation of all these? As you can see, I only put qdvgrab in my code.
- when I translated my files with Qt Linguist I did not have the strings of the ui files
  to translate. Is this normal? Isn't the translation automatic? How to do ? Do I have to include them in my professional file and redo my translation chain (pylupdate, Qt Linguist,?)
- For now, my ts, qm, pro files are at the same level as my program py files.
  But later, I plan to put them in a folder called locale or translation. Knowing that the file launching the application is start_app.py and it is located at the root package (see screenshot), how to import them? My python files will also be in a windows folder at that time
  and therefore at the same level as the others (ui, images, translation). How to import these files into start_app.py so that it can read them.

Here is the code i introduced in start_app.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTranslator, QLocale
from qdvgrab import QdvGrab

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Translate application
    enNativeLanguage = len(sys.argv) == 1
    if enNativeLanguage:
        locale = QLocale()
        # translator.load(locale, "qdvgrab", ".")

    else:
        languageCountry = sys.argv[1]
    translators = []
    for prefixQm in ("qdvgrab.", "qt_", "qtbase_"):
        translator = QTranslator()
        translators.append(translator)
        if enNativeLanguage:
            translator.load(locale, prefixQm)
        else:
            translator.load(prefixQm+languageCountry)
    application.installTranslator(translator)
```

Here is the structure:

[image]

Update with minimal code to reproduce this behaviour:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTranslator, QLocale

from minimal import MiniMal


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Translate application
    enNativeLanguage = len(sys.argv) == 1
    if enNativeLanguage:
        locale = QLocale()
    else:
        languageCountry = sys.argv[1]
    translators = []
    for prefixQm in ("minimal.", "qt_", "qtbase_"):
        translator = QTranslator()
        translators.append(translator)
        if enNativeLanguage:
            translator.load(locale, prefixQm)
        else:
            translator.load(prefixQm+languageCountry)
    application.installTranslator(translator)

    window = MiniMal()
    window.show()
    rc = application.exec_()
    sys.exit(rc)
```

The minimal.py code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from ui.exempleui import Ui_MainWindow


class MiniMal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MiniMal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi()
        self.connectActions()

        format_capture = ['Dv Raw (.dv)', 'DV 2 (.avi)', 'Dv (.avi)', 'Hdv (.m2t)', 'Mpeg 2 (.mpg)', 'Mov (.mov)']
        for format in format_capture:
            self.ui.cmbformatacquisition.addItem(format)
            self.ui.cmbformatacquisition.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def setupUi(self):

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lnetext.setText(self.tr("My Awesome Movie"))
        self.ui.btnsomething.setToolTip(self.tr("Choose the Dv Acquisition mode"))
        self.ui.lnetext.setToolTip(self.tr("Set the Film Name"))
        self.ui.cmbformatacquisition.setToolTip(self.tr("Choose a format"))
        self.ui.chksystray.setToolTip(self.tr("Application in the systray"))
        self.ui.lnetext.setStatusTip(self.tr('The Film name is '))
        self.ui.btnsomething.setStatusTip(self.tr('Dv Acquisition mode is used'))
        self.ui.cmbformatacquisition.setStatusTip(self.tr("Acquisition Mode Changed"))
        self.ui.chksystray.setStatusTip(self.tr('Show this window in the systray'))

    def connectActions(self):
        self.ui.cmbformatacquisition.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.callSomething)
        self.ui.lnetext.textChanged.connect(self.showName)
        self.ui.chksystray.toggled.connect(self.putSystray)
        self.ui.btnsomething.clicked.connect(self.callSomething)

    def changeChoice(self):
        pass

    def putSystray(self):
        pass

    def showName(self):
        pass

    def callSomething(self):
        pass
```

And the ui file code

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(560, 339)
        MainWindow.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedKingdom))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lnetext = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lnetext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 30, 251, 26))
        self.lnetext.setObjectName("lnetext")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 30, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.btnsomething = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnsomething.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 361, 71))
        self.btnsomething.setObjectName("btnsomething")
        self.cmbformatacquisition = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.cmbformatacquisition.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 175, 351, 51))
        self.cmbformatacquisition.setObjectName("cmbformatacquisition")
        self.chksystray = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.chksystray.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 250, 371, 26))
        self.chksystray.setObjectName("chksystray")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 560, 28))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionQuit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionQuit.setObjectName("actionQuit")
        self.actionAbout = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout.setObjectName("actionAbout")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionQuit)
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionAbout)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        self.btnsomething.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Click me"))
        self.chksystray.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Put in this window in the systray"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionQuit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Quit"))
        self.actionAbout.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have updated with a minimal reproducible example (as I don't know how to put a long answer). If you want something else, say it. BTW. I have keep the same structure like before. The next time I will prepare all before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I'm going to see that.